# Архитектура последовательных вызовов в Angular(promise)

Tags: angularjs, запрос, promise

Имеется большое приложение со стандартной *angular*-архитектурой - есть n-фабрик (*factory*) и n-контроллеров (*controller*), в которых эти фабрики создаются.

Каждая фабрика имеет методы-запросы (`$http`), многие из которых запускаются при инициализации фабрики и до настоящего времени они все были независимы (последовательность их выполнения была неважна)

Сейчас в приложение добавился запрос, который должен исполниться первым, т.к. он раздает линки всем остальным запросам приложения.

Конечно, я могу создать переменную-*promise* и в каждом контроллере, который подключает свою фабрику, используя метод *then*, создавать фабрики. То есть как-то так (не обращайте внимание на `$rootScope`, он для того чтобы не вдаваться в подробности архитектуры, всё альфа-глобально):

```
/* Файл A - factory*/
/* Фабричный метод исполняющий запрос на получение ресурсов для всех остальных запросов */
$rootScope.getResources = function () {
    $rootScope.getResourcesPromise = $http({
        url: 'some_path.json'
    }).success(function (data) {
        $rootScope.resources = data
    })
};


/* Файл B - controller*/
$rootScope.getResourcesPromise.then(function () {
    /* Создаем экземпляр фабрики*/
    $rootScope.filter = new Filter();
});


/* Файл С - controller*/
$rootScope.getResourcesPromise.then(function () {
    /* Создаем экземпляр фабрики*/
    $rootScope.sort = new Sort();
});


/* Файл С - controller*/
$rootScope.getResourcesPromise.then(function () {
    /* Создаем экземпляр фабрики*/
    $rootScope.actions = new Actions();
});

и т.д.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли паттерн, который позволяет создавать многослойную архитектуру запросов более красивым способом?

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Get options
    var categories = $http.get(PATH+'-categories', {cache: true}),
        formats    = $http.get(PATH+'-formats', {cache: true});
    $q.all([categories, formats]).then(function(response){
          scope.categories = response[0].data;
          scope.formats    = response[1].data;
    });
```